# Retrieve data from value in database using Javascript Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, database

I am a new to Django. I am using datatables (https://datatables.net/) to populate my data. Could anyone please give some advice on what I should change in my code ? I have data in database but I have no idea why the data wasn't being shown in the table.

**views.py**

```
from django.core import serializers

def ltimesheet(request): 
    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
    query_results = json_serializer.serialize( Timesheet.objects.all(), ensure_ascii=False )
    data={'query_results':query_results}
    return render(request, 'hrfinance/list_timesheet.html', data)
```

this is how my **script** looks like

```
var dataSet = '{{ query_results|escapejs }}';

/*create the table*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Student ID" },
            { title: "Student Name" },
            { title: "Start Date" },
            { title: "End Date" }
        ]
    } );
```

Comment: Are you sure that `dataSet` is not empty ?

Comment: Why are the results in quotes? And where is your script?

Comment: @NabIlovich how do i check whether my dataSet is empty or not ? becuase i tried to print {{query_results}} in my template and it shows there are data in it

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid the results in quotes are the data in my database. My script has been given in the question

Comment: `console.log(dataSet)` and check your browser console.

Comment: first of all, make sure you pass data to html.
And the second: you have to use the same name (the name in views.py is data so it should be data in html - js)

Comment: @NabIlovich i have added that line "console.log(dataSet)" in my script. and it seems like it is empty with weird parameter 0 and . "DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4" this is the error i got

Comment: @NamNguyễn i passed data into html by this line "var dataSet = '{{ query_results|escapejs }}';", is that the correct way to pass data ? so u mean i have to use 'data' in html-js which is the line "data : data" ?

Comment: return render(request, 'hrfinance/list_timesheet.html', {'query_results':query_results}) use this in view and do a console.log in the html and check if you get data

Comment: @Nobody I meant where is your script situated. In the html file or separately?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid inside html file

Comment: @Nobody as i knew. the data from Server pass to HTML is normal data (not Json). So you can use it and show in html right away.
But in the case of data table. The data should be Json, so just make sure you give it the right type of data

Comment: @NamNguyễn are u saying the data i use in my JS has to be Json ?

Comment: Have you done with it?
You should try to show your data has been passed. (show it in a textfield is ok)

And then try to use it as default value (var xxx = yourdata) and check if your datable can show it or not.
If it still have problem, please add more code (log)

Answer (score 0):

`django.core.serializers` will serialize your models into the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "pk": "4b678b301dfd8a4e0dad910de3ae245b",
       "model": "yourapp.Timesheet",
        "fields": {
            "student_name": "Joe",
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

you can do:

- in the template, iterate the json as is returned by the serializer
- in the view, serialize your models by hand
- use [`djangorestframework`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) serializers, although it may be too much

Comment: do u mean like this in my view :                    json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
    query_results = json_serializer.serialize( Timesheet.objects.all(), ensure_ascii=False )

Comment: yes it is the same. so i shouldn't do it like this ?

Comment: Well, if you use the same code you will have the same results. Somewhere you need to format the json according to what `datatables` expects